# Why isn't my Formik form showing warning message? React, Formik

Tags: reactjs, formik

I'm trying to get some basic front end form validation done using Formik. I've validated the user but the error message is not showing on my front end.

I am looking to display an error message iF my form does not meet my validation schema.

My validation schema:

```js
import * as yup from 'yup';

export const userSignUpSchema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup
    .string()
    .min(4, "Too short")
    .max(20, "Too long")
    .required("Required"),
  email: yup
    .string()
    .email("Invalid email")
    .required("Required"),
  password: yup
    .string()
    .min(4, "Too short")
    .max(20, "Too long")
    .required("Required"),
  confirmPassword: yup
    .string()
    .min(4, "Too short")
    .max(20, "Too long")
    .required("Required")
});
```

My SignUp component

```
<Formik
  initialValues={{
    name: '',
    email: '',
    password: ''
  }}
  validationSchema={userSignUpSchema}
  onSubmit={createUser}
>
  <Form className="form">
    <label>Display Name</label>
    <Field name="name" type="text" onChange={
      (e) => {setUsernameReg(e.target.value);
    }} />
    <ErrorMessage
      name="name"
      component="div"
      className="invalid-feedback"
    />

    <label>Email Address</label>
    <Field name="email" type="email" onChange={
      (e) => {setEmailReg(e.target.value);
    }} />
    <ErrorMessage
      name="email"
      component="div"
      className="invalid-feedback"
    />

    <label>Password</label>
    <Field name="password" type="password" onChange={
      (e) => {setUsernameReg(e.target.value);
    }}/>
    <ErrorMessage
      name="password"
      component="div"
      className="invalid-feedback"
    />

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </Form>
</Formik>
```

Comment: You have't specified `values` and `errors` objects using Formik hooks or render props. Please share all of your component code

Comment: Please see:   https://pastebin.pl/view/e4f9b757

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't show the error messages, I just had a look at your code, it seems to be working.